# Colorbar shows auto ticks in addition to the one I specify

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to add my own ticks to my colorbar. However, in addition to the ticks that I specify matplotlib continues to print its own ticks.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

ax.plot(data)

cm = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
cNorm = colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=10)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(
    cax, cmap=cm, norm=cNorm, orientation='vertical')
cbar.set_ticks([1,3,10])
cbar.set_ticklabels(["one", "three", "ten"])
cbar.set_label("awesome cbar")

fig.savefig("test.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Output with Matplotlib 3.2.0: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imUMD.png)

I only want the ticks that I specified ("one", "three", "ten").

Comment: The undesired ticks are the minor ticks. You can turn them off. `cbar.ax.minorticks_off()`

Comment: You are right, didn't catch that. Thank you!